# Api calls in the app is not able to be debugged in Charles/Fiddler (Bypassing proxy)

Tags: android, xamarin, proxy, xamarin.android, charles-proxy

My App is developed using Xamarin.Android. When I try to do API debugging using Charles, I am not able to see the APIs in Charles. But I can see APIs of the other Apps installed in my device.

I have set the proxy in the android device taking IP from my system.

Here is the code which I have used in the PCL code, which is used for both IOS and Android.

```
return new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl),
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout)
        };


public class AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   public AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) :    base(innerHandler)
   {
   }
   protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       //------
   }
}
```

This is common code written in PCL. 
In IOS APIs are not getting bypassed from the proxy and able to track it in Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mono HttpClient isn't using the proxy settings. Configure your app to use the native `ClientHandler`.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_6/xamarin.android_6.1/#Native_HttpClientHandler

- add a file to your project
- insert `XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE=Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler`
- set Build Action to `AndroidEnvironment`

[image]

**or** create your HttpClient like:

```
var client = new HttpClient (new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler ());
```

Comment: The HttpClient code is written in PCL, it's common for both IOS and Android. So I don't think I can use 'Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler' in my code

Comment: You can. As I said.

Comment: In my PCL code I have used this code "new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler(new NativeMessageHandler()))" - "public class AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler : DelegatingHandler"

Comment: You can, if you use a factory and use dependency injection or something else to resolve the factory at runtime.

Comment: Now I am able to see Http calls, but not Https calls.